# Bootstrap table headers are not aligned properly in vuejs component

Tags: html, css, vue.js, html-table, bootstrap-5

How can I make the headers and column bodies of my Vue.js DataGrid component aligned properly when using the vuedraggable package to enable dragging and reordering of columns?

Here is my current code for the DataGrid.vue component:

```
<template>
  <div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table table-striped table-hover" v-if="selectedColumns.length > 0">
      <thead>
        <draggable :list="selectedColumns" group="columns" @end="onEnd">
          <th v-for="(column, index) in selectedColumns" :key="index">{{ column }}</th>
        </draggable>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <draggable v-model="mergedData" group="rows">
          <tr v-for="(data, index) in mergedData" :key="index">
            <td v-for="(column, index) in selectedColumns" :key="index">
              {{ data[column.toLowerCase().replace(' ', '_')] !== undefined ? data[column.toLowerCase().replace(' ', '_')] : 'N/A' }}
            </td>
          </tr>
        </draggable>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import draggable from 'vuedraggable';

export default {
  name: 'DataGrid',
  components: {
    draggable,
  },
  props: {
    selectedColumns: {
      type: Array,
      required: true,
    },
    mergedData: {
      type: Array,
      required: true,
    },
  },
  methods: {
    onEnd(event) {
      const oldIndex = event.oldIndex;
      const newIndex = event.newIndex;
      this.selectedColumns.splice(newIndex, 0, this.selectedColumns.splice(oldIndex, 1)[0]);
    },
  },
};
</script>

<style scoped>
/* Add any custom styles here */
</style>
```

I have tried wrapping the table element with a div with the table-responsive class, but the headers and column bodies are still not aligned properly. How can I make the table content aligned properly while maintaining responsiveness and the dragging capability?

My current table looks as follows:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I able to fix the issue,

Since I'm using `vuedgraggable` library, it was wrapping my `<th>...</th>` dynamically adding an additional `<div>`.

So it was like this,

```
<thead>
 <tr>
  <div>
   <th></th> 
   ...
   ...
   ...
   <th></th>
  </div>
 </tr>
</thead>
```

It was wrapping the `<td>` as well with a `<div>`

```
<tbody>
 <div>
  <tr>
   <td></td>
   ...
   ...
   ...
   <td></td>
  </tr>
 </div>
</tbody>
```

So I've added following CSS to my vuejs component,

```
tbody > div:first-child {
    display: contents!important;
}
thead tr > div:first-child {
  display: contents!important;
}
```

This has fixed my header and column content alignment issue keeping the dragging function untouched.